# External Accessory bluetooth issue in IOS11

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

I have App which uses external accessory platform to connect to iPod App.
Before iOS11 bluetooth was working very much fine with automatically reconnecting when ever my app restart. I don't have to go to setting all the time.

from iOS11, in setting it shows device is connected whenever i restart my App but it does not actually connect to it i had to disconnect or to forget device and fresh connection.

I notice that this is true for Bluetooth devices on iOS11.

is it a BUG in iOS11? or some keys i need to add to the `.plist`?

Thanks

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue. My device is acting as if it connected but it is not sending the commands as it does perfectly with the same app in ios 10.. (this happens when a disconnections occurs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug on iOS side.
I am following this Apple developer forum thread for a while https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79395.

Someone found that the iOS 11.2 beta solved the problem. I am currently trying on my side with my external accessory.